# What does the foo method do?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
let arr = [3, 5, 7];
arr.foo = "hello";

for (let i in arr) {
   console.log(i); 

}

for (let i of arr) {
   console.log(i); 

}
```

I would like to know what the foo method is used for in JS

Comment: This is not a method. You are setting a property named 'foo' on the array.

Comment: oh well, thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Here `foo` is not a method, it is a user defined property where you are assigning string value i.e. `hello` to it.

```js
let arr = [3, 5, 7]
arr.foo = "hello";

for (let i of arr) {
   console.log(i); //Print array elements

}

console.log(arr.foo); //This will print hello
```

Documentation : [let variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Description)

Answer (score 0):

the foo is a property as mentioned before..
if you run your code, you get this:

```
0
1
2
foo
3
5
7
```

where

```
for (let i in arr) {
   console.log(i); //Print property names

}

for (let i of arr) {
   console.log(i); //Print values inside the array

}
```

why "hello" is not printed?
because and not exactly we can consider foo as a variable inside arr...

console.log(arr.foo); //This will print hello

Answer (score 0):

Think in your variable called arr as a object, you  has 3 keys with its vallues  they are 0 : 3 , 1 : 5 , 2 : 7 but
when you do this,  arr.foo = "hello”; you’re making a new key with the string “hello” as a value

```
let arr = [3, 5, 7];
arr.foo = "hello";

for (let i in arr) {
console.log(i); 
// this will print the keys
}

for (let i of arr) {
console.log(i); 
// this will print the values
}
```